# Does feedback really sent when I try to vote things?

Tags: support, post-feedback

It seems like *good* way of being nice to users: I mean, you simply say that you got their feedback instead of forcing them to sign up / log in.

But I am a bit suspicious about it so I wanted to ask. Is it really sent and (if yes) does it affect anything?

Comment: yes, and no, respectively.  It's recorded, but nothing is actually done with it.